# c# Unexpected numbers in double variable in for loop

Tags: c#

```
for (double i = 0; i < 0.05; i+= 0.001)
{
            //do something
}
```

In this for loop,

I thought the count would go as follows: 0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, etc., but it becomes 0.0090000000000000011 instead of 0.009.

Why is such conversion possible?

Comment: Use `decimal` rather than `double`.

Comment: Double can only describe rational numbers like `x/2^n`, not `x/10^n`

Answer (score 2):

The resolution of the double/float is not infinite.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-5.0#Precision)

> Because some numbers cannot be represented exactly as fractional binary values, floating-point numbers can only approximate real numbers.